# In a differential equation: Will all rewritings yield a solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been asked to solve the following differential equation:

$$y\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=(y+1)^2$$

In the book, it's solved as follows:

$$\frac{y}{(y+1)^2}\,\mathrm{d}y=\mathrm{d}x$$

And then we integrate both sides. Now, I noticed that this rewriting is a particular choice for it. There are also other rewritings:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{(y+1)^2}{y} \hspace{1cm} \mathrm{d}y=\frac{(y+1)^2}{y}\,\mathrm{d}x \hspace{1cm} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y}=\frac{y}{(y+1)^2}$$

These are just some of them. This may be a very silly question but: Will all of those rewritings yield solutions to our original equation? I noticed that for some of them, the solution is going to be different, for example: In the second, it won't be defined for $y=0$, in the fourth it won't be defined for $y=-1$.

I also noticed that in doing this, the "solutions" look very different, for example:

- Solving $\frac{y}{(y+1)^2}\,\mathrm{d}y=\mathrm{d}x$ we obtain: $\frac{1}{y+1}+\log{\left(y+1\right)}=x+c$.
- Solving $\mathrm{d}y=\frac{(y+1)^2}{y}\,\mathrm{d}x$ we obtain: $x \left(y+1\right)^2+c=y^2$.

Comment: $y=0$ is not a solution of the DE. But $y=-1$ is indeed a solution.

Comment: Yes if you divide by $(y+1)^2$ as in the book you have to consider the case $y=-1$ separately. Otherwise you should always get the same solution.

Comment: $x \left(y+1\right)^2+c=y^2$ is not a solution. $\frac{1}{y+1}+\log{\left(y+1\right)}=x+c$ should be $\frac{1}{y+1}+\log{\left|y+1\right|}=x+c$

Comment: Your second solution is wrong as you assume that $y$ does not depend on $x$ which is not the case.

Comment: @Vasya What is the meaning of assuming that?

Comment: @BillyRubina: What I was trying to say is that $\int y(x)dx \ne y(x)\cdot x + C$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the relation

$dy=\frac{(y+1)^2}{y}dx$

We have $\int dy = y + c$

But the second integral is not of a known form. We are blocked for the integral:

$\int \frac{(y(x)+1)^2}{y(x)} dx$

There would be a missing y' for example.

Only the first writing by separating the variables gives a result. This is actually a shortcut using the differential forms. But this can be rigorously justified by:

$\frac{y(x)}{(y(x)+1)^2} y'(x)=1$

which gives by integrating

$\int \frac{y(x)}{(y(x)+1)^2} y'(x) dx =\int 1. dx$

By changing variable z=y(x) in the first integral:

$\int \frac{z}{(z+1)^2} dz =\int 1. dx = x+c$

$\frac{1}{z+1}+\ln|z+1|+d=x+c$

Returning to the old variable

$\frac{1}{y(x)+1}+\ln|y(x)+1|+d=x+c$

etc.